# help with t-sql linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server

Based on the 2 databases below:

```
Database_A on Server_1
Database_B on Server_2
```

I have `created a linked server to Database_B on Server_1 instance by name 'LS_B'.`

I have a huge script file which basically creates required tables, functions, views, and stored procs on Database_A.

These functions, views and stored procs in turn refer to Database_B tables.

Problem is I have to now go and include `OPENQUERY(LS_B,<query refering to database_b table>)` everywhere in the script file.

For instance

```
create procedure some_proc
as
begin
    select * from openquery(LS_B, 'select * from [Database_B].[dbo].[Table_1]');
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Pls. suggest.

Thanks

**update**

why does this fail

```
select top (50) * from LS_B.[Database_B].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

while the below works

```
select * from OpenQuery(LS_B, 'select top (50) * from Database_B.dbo.Table_1')
```

The error message on executing the first query is

Cannot process the object ""Database_B"."dbo"."Table_1"". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LS_B" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object

Both servers are on same domain.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` is only useful if you're connecting to a database other than SQL Server (or older versions that don't support particular syntax) because of the query pass-through.  The pass-through lets you write for the other database in native SQL - IE: TO_DATE on Oracle, etc.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks for explaining that. I have edited my question to present the new issue that i am facing. Can you pls. provide some suggestion as to what can be done about it? Thanks.

Comment: Tested on SQL Server 2005 - works for me, with and without hard brackets.  Are you sure you're testing from an instance where that linked server instance is present?  In Management Studio, in the Object Explorer - what's listed under Server Objects\Linked Servers (assuming you have permissions to see)?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: its shows TFSDBTIER

Comment: In your error message it says the linked server is called LS_B but in your example it says it is called TFSDBTIER, is this just a typo or does the error message refer to a different linked server.

Comment: @Ben: Sorry about that. "LS_B" was just a dummy name i used. TFSDBTIER is the actual link server name which i just copied from actual error message. Sorry about the confusion. Rectified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both servers are  SQL servers you can use the following syntax:

```
select * from LS_B.[Database_B].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

It would depend on your exisitng syntax whether this would make it easier to do a find and replace.

You could also create a bunch of views on server 1 named after the tables refered to in the sps, then have these views refernce the linked server:

```
CREATE VIEW Table_1
AS
select * from LS_B.[Database_B].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

Comment: +1: You beat me, here's a link to the documentation on qualified name syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172676%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: A [synonym](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) is an alternative to a view.

Comment: @Ben: I get the below error on executing 

Cannot process the object ""Database_B"."dbo"."Table_1"". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LS_B" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

But the same thing works when i execute

select * from openquery(LS_B, 'select * from [Database_B].[dbo].[Table_1]')

Comment: Yes that might be a better alternative.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser, hmm strange it is valid syntax.  Do you get the same error if you use actual field names in the select statement instead of *

Comment: @Ben: Yes i get the same error with actual field names as well. I have edited my question to reflect the error.

Comment: @Ben: "You could also create a bunch of views on server 1 named after the tables refered to in the sps, then have these views refernce the linked server". That is an interesting option. But will this affect performance? I thought the earlier option (referring to table using 4 part schema)  might filter results on server_2 while creating view will fetch all rows from server_2 and filter on server_1. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but i don't believe using views will make much difference to this.  However OMG Ponies' sugestion synonyms is probably a better way than using views.

Comment: Thanks Ben. 

@OMG Ponies: Any suggestion in terms of performance on View vs Synonyms?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: No, a synonym just means you don't have to type the qualified name out in full (four part for linked servers).  As long as you aren't doing any functions on the columns, `SELECT * FROM synonym` will perform exactly the same as `SELECT * FROM linked_view`.

Comment: Thanks @OMG Ponies and @Ben for the help.

Comment: I was trying to access a mapped sql 2008 server from sql 2005 with "SELECT * FROM [server]..[db].[view]" and got the same error written on question than I changed query syntax as your sample one                "SELECT * FROM [server].[db].dbo.[view]"   bingo ! worked ...